# React Router: Rendering entirely/dynamically from a route-config

Tags: react-router-v4

Looking at the [react router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) for the Route Config feature

I'm wondering if instead of hard coding the Link tags, if we could dynamically render straight from the routes array.  EG: in the example they are hard coding the top level tags Taco and Sanwiches

That would also mean when we click on a top level route, the children are shown dynamically... and so on, for however deep it goes

To make it easier: I am less interested in each level being its own component... each can just be a page with child links... so the same component at every level

Any ideas of how to set this up?